# Как в Alfresco заменить документ в первой его версии

Tags: alfresco

Alfresco Community v.5.1.0 (201605)

У документа есть несколько версий, можно ли как то подменить самую первую версию документа на другой?
Эта первая версия документа доступна по ссылке `alfresco/service/api/node/content/versionStore/version2Store/{uuid}`,
как я понял через `workspace/SpaceStore` можно смотреть только последнюю версию документа.
Так же не понимаю как найти эту версию через `licene`
Если есть вариант сделать это с помощью JavaScript консоли, то было бы здорово.

Comment: я пробовал через JavaScript console сначала найти текущую версию ```var src = search.findNode("workspace://SpaceStore/{uuid}")```, потом взять первую версию ```var firstVersion = src.getVersionHistory()[7].getNode();
print(firstVersion.getContent());```
тут показывает код документа т.к. документ pdf.
Вот было бы здорово как-то через ```setContent()``` просто поменять содержимое документа, но что-то мне подсказывает что этот метод какая-то дичь)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Разобрался
Через `setContent()` не получится, потому что предыдущие версии документов хранятся в отдельном хранилице `versionStore://version2Store/` которое является READONLY.
К примеру у документа существует 3 версии, 3-я версия является текущей и нам надо заменить 1-ю версию документа на другой файл (важно чтобы mimeType совпадал, иначе нужно будет отдельно править и тип документа).
Для этого вычислим uuid первой версии документа через JacaScript Console:

```js
// получаем текущий документ
var doc = search.findNode("workspace://SpaceStore/{uuid}");
// массив всех версий
var allVersionDoc = doc.getVersionHistory();
print(allVersionDoc);
// первой версией документа является последний элемент массива версий
var firstVersionDoc = allVersion[2];
// получаем хранилище и uuid 1-й версии (versionStore/version2Store/{uuid})
print(firstVersionDoc.getNode());
```

- Берем наш `versionStore://version2Store/{uuid}` и идем в консоль администратора (`hostname.ru/alfresco/service/admin/admin-nodebrowser`)
- Выбираем `Просмотр объектов` -> Хранилище: `workspace://version2Store` -> Запрос: `noderef`: `versionStore://version2Store/{uuid}` -> `Выполнить`
- В результате поиска находим в колонке `Имя` `cm:content` и берем из колонки `Значение` часть после `contentUrl=store://` у меня это `contentUrl=store://` **2020/3/13/{uuid}.bin**
- Берем новый документ `NewDoc.pdf` и переименовываем его (с изменением расширения) в `{uuid}.bin` из предыдущего пункта
- Заходим на сервер в `D:\alfresco\alf_data\contentstore\`**2020\3\13{uuid}.bin** и заменяем документ на вновь созданный